# Regex: change strings of numbers to standard parseable format

Tags: regex, number-formatting

I am trying to wirte a replacer function that will take a string and if it identifies it as a number, will change it into a standard format number (that is parseable in most languages)

Is it possible to achive that with single regex? Eventually with a few subsequent replacements?

I am using

```
scala org.apache.spark.sql.functions.regexp_replace 

regexp_replace(col(x), "regex that will identify number", "standard format number"))
```

standard format exemples: '-2421', '22.4536', '6.25367E-08', '6.25367e-08' <- these are proven to be parsable to float

possible strings I may deal with, and what I want to replace them with:

```
111,222,333.444 -> 111222333.444
111,222,333,444 -> 111222333444
-1,2 -> -1.2
1,22 -> 1.22
1,222 -> 1222
1,000 -> 1000 (if there are 3 digits after commas, it is thousands separator, not decimal)
```

There may be '%' at the end of number string, in this case, the rules above apply:

```
1,22% -> 1.22%
```

Other signs or letters (with exceptions of e/E like in '6.25367E-08') disqualify string as a number (and thus no replacement will be done)

Answer (score 0):

#### Probably not possible with a single regex.

The issue comes from the fact that you have to first identify a string as a "valid number" (doable) and then identify sub-parts of that string to remove (not doable in a single regex).

Luckily, you're writing a function, so if you're willing to check the string against more than one regex, here's a few that will address your requirements. Note that all of these assume you are *only* passing in a number, and nothing else.

---

**Thousands separators**

`^-?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+(?:\.\d+)?$`

This regex asserts that between the start and end of the line, there's an optional negative sign, one to three digits, followed by a repeated non-capture group. This non capture group is a comma followed by 3 digits, and is repeated one or more times. The ending non-capture group is an optional decimal point, followed by one or more digits. Note that this will only match thousands-separator commas, and won't match comma-less numbers like `12`.

If this group matches, you'll need to identify and remove the commas. This can be done with a second, much simpler regex: `,`

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/6OBCDw/12/)

---

**Commas instead of decimals**

`^-?\d+,(?:(?:\d{1,2})|(?:\d{4,}))$`

This regex asserts that between the start and end of the line, there's an optional negative sign, one or more digits, and a comma. The regex then chooses 1 or 2 digits after the comma, or > 4 digits after a comma (but not 3, that's thousands!). If you only care about comma-decimals with one or two digits, like in your example, that's `^-?\d+,\d{1,2}$`

If this group matches, you'll need to identify the commas, and replace them with periods. This can also be done with the regex `,`

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/6OBCDw/13/)

---

**Commas instead of decimals, with % at the end**

`^-?\d+,\d+%$`

(I'm going to assume that if there's a `%` at the end, it's a decimal no matter what - the regex treats `1,000%` as `1.000%`.)

This regex asserts that between the start and end of the line, there's an optional negative sign, one or more digits, a comma, and then one or more digits, followed by a `%` sign.

If this group matches, you'll need to identify and remove commas - you know the drill.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/6OBCDw/14/)

---

**Scientific notation**

(You didn't specify what should be done with scientific notation, so this regex matches commas or periods.)

`^-?\d[.\,]\d+[eE]-?\d+$`

This regex asserts that between the start and end of the line, there's an optional negative sign, *exactly one* digit, a period or comma, one or more digits, a lowercase or capital E, an optional negative sign, and one or more digits.

I'm not sure what you planned to do with this regex, but I assume you've got what you need to edit the string by now.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/6OBCDw/17/)

---

**All of them together**

If you just wanna see whether you can parse the string as a number or not.

`(?:^-?\d[.\,]\d+[eE]-?\d+$)|(?:^-?\d+,\d+%$)|(^-?\d+,(?:(?:\d{1,2})|(?:\d{4,}))$)|(?:^-?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+(?:\.\d+)?$)`

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/6OBCDw/16/)

---

Good luck!